# How can I view PHP source code on a live site?

Tags: php, security

Is it possible to view the PHP code of a live website ?

Comment: I hope not. Something like this would be a security nightmare.

Comment: I added the security tag b/c it seemed pertinent

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, as it is interpreted on the server-side and the results are sent to the user. If you want to view the source code of a site you control in-browser, consider the [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) extension for [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), or just access your site files with your preferred method.

Comment: They can access our data from our house. Then why we can't know about them ? data includes ip, location, ISP, Country etc. http://ip-api.com/json

Answer (score 9):

Usually, no, as others have said, unless of course this is something you want to be the case. Then you can set it up so that using .phps (or any other extension really, but this is the norm) will display the source code of the page (with syntax coloring I believe). Something like:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

in your apache configuration should do the trick.

Note, you will need to save your .php files with a .phps for their source to be displayed.

Comment: A [`SetHandler` statement](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#sethandler) inside a [`<FilesMatch \.phps$>` section](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) also works, and seems to be how CentOS does it in their Apache configs. This isn't much use outside teaching or learning PHP (obviously a security concern for any "important" PHP applications, as mentioned elsewhere), but on Unix platforms, you can just make a symbolic link to the original source with a `.phps` extension, which makes it like kind of a "view PHP source".

Answer (score 8):

Everyone is wrong! Yes, it is possible! But if you do see the code in your web browser then this would be a serious security breach or some major trouble in the web server. I've seen it happen once, where some dumb administrator had removed the PHP extension for IIS thus the browser provided all sources as text files instead of executing them.

Then again, there is an alternative method, which is through FTP. Most websites give access to their file system through FTP, so administrators don't need physical access to the system. You will need to know username and password, plus the FTP address to get access, but once you have this information, you have access to the whole site. Useful for administrators, yet also a very good reason to be very careful with passwords.

Comment: I think your first paragraph was already covered by *"unless the admin screwed up"*, which was mentioned at least twice.

Comment: True, but those answers replied with "no", while that is incorrect. There are all kinds of causes -including administrators screwing things up- that could cause PHP sources to be shown. It *might* also be possible if the server application (IIS or Apache) itself has a bug or hack that would bypass the standard behavior. (Thus a bug.) Fortunately, these kinds of bugs are rare but hackers might be able to modify the behavior of the server software to mess things up. And no server is 100% hacker-proof!

Answer (score 4):

Current Page add to php code:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php

```
 <?php show_source(__FILE__); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to the files on the live server?  If so yes, otherwise no, it is only possible to see the result of the script execution.

Answer (score 2):

No, unless the server admin screwed up.

Answer (score 2):

Not if PHP is configured properly.

PHP is served already interpreted to the visitor.

Seeing the PHP code on a live website would be considered hacking which is probably outside the ethical scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: There's an ethical scope of SO?

Comment: No, but we can pretend there is.

Comment: hmm that would be interesting

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.
Because the server side script (here PHP scripts) execute on the web server and its output is embedded inside HTML which is then thrown back to your browser.
So all you can view is the HTML.
Just imagine, if what you asked was possible, then evryone would have the source code of facebook, flipkart in their hands now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few sites that allow you to view their PHP source. Try googling for [inurl:viewsource.php](http://google.com/search?q=inurl:viewsource.php) (my site should turn up in there somewhere :)).

Also you can view [php.net](http://php.net)'s source: http://www.php.net/source.php?url=/index.php

Answer (score 0):

check out `php://input` and `php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=<filepath>`, eg. http://level11.tasteless.eu/index.php?file=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=config.easy.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

The only NORMAL way to view PHP source code sitting in some file is to use **phps** extension, instead of normal **php** extension. If you make the file extension .phps, decently configured server will output a color-formated source instead of generated html that one would expect. Any other scenario than this one is considered a BIG flaw and the one behind should - panic.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible as this is considered as security breach