# How to download php scripts from a live server to local system with security?

Tags: php, security, curl

I want to download project files specially (php) files from live site (shared hosting server) to my local development machine, If I am the owner for both locations, what is the secure way to download by using curl or any other way with php?

I wrote some code it does not download php script but the result of its execution.

```
$remoteUrl = $remoteConfig['remoteUrl'];
$remoteUrl = substr($remoteUrl, 0, strrpos( $remoteUrl, '/'));
$filePath = $_POST['file'];

$url = $remoteUrl .'/'. $filePath;
$downloaded = __DIR__ .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $filePath;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$st = curl_exec($ch);
$fd = fopen($downloaded, 'w');
fwrite($fd, $st);
if( fclose($fd) ) {
    echo json_encode(['response' => true, 'msg' => 'File Downloaded']);
}

curl_close($ch);
exit();
```

Comment: you will need to use ftp\sftp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view PHP on live site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319603/how-to-view-php-on-live-site)

Comment: PHP is not returned to the browser. So you can't

Comment: @zarpio As the owner of the sites, you should have administrative access to do things like upload and download source code, as well as configure security for your site.  Shared hosting sites typically use a "Control Panel" to configure your access privileges for doing this, although this varies widely from one hosting provider to another.  Check your host's documentation, wiki, or support knowledgebase for the specific details of how to do that.  If your sites are with different hosts, it may be completely different instructions for each site.

Comment: I was not expecting this kind of response from the lions of stackoverflow, anyways can you please explain what the link says https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-force-download-of-a-php-file-instead-of-execute-it-on-server/4173   and isn't this possible to upload/download by php-ftp here is another link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-php-and-ftp--net-20012

Comment: I have added the solution guys, this was not a difficult job. And thanks for them who voted-down my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one was going to reply me but I found a way how can I download php(code) files from the live-site(shared hosting server) to local development-machine.

See the following link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-php-and-ftp--net-20012
It helped me completly.

Edited little bit as under

```
class FTPClient
{
    // *** Class variables
    private $connectionId;
    private $loginOk = false;
    private $messageArray = array();

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    private function logMessage($message)
    {
        $this->messageArray[] = $message;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messageArray;
    }

    public function connect($server, $ftpUser, $ftpPassword, $isPassive = false)
    {
        // *** Set up basic connection
        $this->connectionId = ftp_connect($server);

        // *** Login with username and password
        $loginResult = ftp_login($this->connectionId, $ftpUser, $ftpPassword);

        // *** Sets passive mode on/off (default off)
        ftp_pasv($this->connectionId, $isPassive);

        // *** Check connection
        if ((!$this->connectionId) || (!$loginResult)) {
            $this->logMessage('FTP connection has failed!');
            $this->logMessage('Attempted to connect to ' . $server . ' for user ' . $ftpUser, true);
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->logMessage('Connected to ' . $server . ', for user ' . $ftpUser);
            $this->loginOk = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function makeDir($directory)
    {
        if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            // *** If creating a directory is successful...
            if (@ftp_mkdir($this->connectionId, $directory)) {
                $this->logMessage('Directory "' . $directory . '" created successfully');
                return true;
            } else {
                // *** ...Else, FAIL.
                $this->logMessage('Failed creating directory "' . $directory . '"');
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $this->logMessage('Failed creating directory "' . $directory . '" already exist.');
        }

    }

    public function uploadFile($fileFrom, $fileTo)
    {
        // *** Set the transfer mode
        $asciiArray = array('txt', 'csv');
        $value = explode('.', $fileFrom);
        $extension = end($value);
        if (in_array($extension, $asciiArray)) {
            $mode = FTP_ASCII;
        } else {
            $mode = FTP_BINARY;
        }

        // *** Upload the file
        $upload = ftp_put($this->connectionId, $fileTo, $fileFrom, $mode);

        // *** Check upload status
        if (!$upload) {

            $this->logMessage('FTP upload has failed!');
            return false;

        } else {
            $this->logMessage('Uploaded "' . $fileFrom . '" as "' . $fileTo);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function changeDir($directory)
    {
        if (ftp_chdir($this->connectionId, $directory)) {
            $this->logMessage('Current directory is now: ' . ftp_pwd($this->connectionId));
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->logMessage('Couldn\'t change directory');
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getDirListing($directory = '.', $parameters = '-la')
    {
        // get contents of the current directory
        // $contentsArray = ftp_nlist($this->connectionId, $parameters . ' ' . $directory);
        $contentsArray = ftp_nlist($this->connectionId, $directory);

        return $contentsArray;
    }

    public function downloadFile($fileFrom, $fileTo)
    {

        // *** Set the transfer mode
        $asciiArray = array('txt', 'csv');

        $value = explode('.', $fileFrom);
        $extension = end($value);
        //$extension  = end(explode('.', $fileFrom));
        if (in_array($extension, $asciiArray)) {
            $mode = FTP_ASCII;
        } else {
            $mode = FTP_BINARY;
        }

        // try to download $remote_file and save it to $handle
        if (ftp_get($this->connectionId, $fileTo, $fileFrom, $mode, 0)) {
            $this->logMessage(' file "' . $fileTo . '" successfully downloaded');
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->logMessage('There was an error downloading file "' . $fileFrom . '" to "' . $fileTo . '"');
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function __deconstruct()
    {
        if ($this->connectionId) {
            ftp_close($this->connectionId);
        }
    }

}
```

Usage below

```
// *** Define your host, username, and password
define('FTP_HOST', 'host');
define('FTP_USER', 'user');
define('FTP_PASS', 'password');
define('PASSIVE_MODE', TRUE);


// *** Create the FTP object
    $ftpObj = new FTPClient();
    // *** Connect
    if ($ftpObj -> connect(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS, PASSIVE_MODE)) {
        // *** Then add FTP code here

        $filePath = $_POST['file'];
        $path = dirname($filePath);
        $fileName = basename($filePath);
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0755, true);
        }

        // *** Change to folder
        $ftpObj->changeDir($path);

        $fileFrom = $fileName; # The location on the remote
        $fileTo = $filePath; # Source dir to save to

        // *** Download file
        $ftpObj->downloadFile($fileFrom, $fileTo);

        echo json_encode(['response' => true, 'msg' => 'File Downloaded']);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['response' => false, 'msg' => $ftpObj -> getMessages()]);
    }
```

And finally I have done...

Comment: To be a bit fussy: No curl in there.